# Can electric field orientation inside a capacitor be changed in a negligibly small duration?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

Can electrostatic field orientation inside a capacitor be changed in a negligibly small duration if a plate is suddenly brought closer to the other? I have been wondering about this thing ever since I saw questions regarding changing configuration of capacitors. So can it change in a small duration?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "field orientation"? And are you talking about a parallel-plate capacitor? If so, the electric field inside will depend on the polarity of the plates -- i.e., which plate has excess positive charge relative to the other plate. The electric field will point toward the plate with the lower amount of positive charge.

If the plates are brought closer together, until they are close enough that the electrical potential between them is large enough to cause a breakdown of the dielectric material separating them and the charges can move across the plates, the *polarity* of the plates should not change. Once the breakdown occurs, the charges on the two plates might rearrange.

Comment: suppose 3 plates are kept at seperations of d and then the middle plate is moved very quickly such that charge is not redistributed so like will the field in the d/2 region exist or not.. I should've  mentioned it clearly i guess

Answer (score 0):

The polarity of the charge on a capacitor in a radio (or TV) frequency circuit changes quite rapidly. That suggests that such a change can occur much more rapidly than you can move a plate.